# Centos freezes, when trying to open crontab

Tags: centos, freeze, cron, crontab, centos-7

I'm trying to open crontab, but when i type it the whole os just freezes... I thought, maybe that's because vim isn't installed, but it is. I also checked the cron.allow and cron.deny files, but they were empty.

Comment: Could you explain how you are opening crontab? What OS?

Comment: I'm logged in on root, and i type the crontab command.

Comment: Seems you used `crontab` instead of `crontab -e`. If option is omitted, default is `crontab -r` which is delete (check with `crontab --help`)

Comment: Oh, Oops i didn't remember that :). Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jojo - Thanks for your comment. Here the proposed answer:

Seems you used `crontab` instead of `crontab -e`. If option is omitted, default is `crontab -r` which is delete (check with `crontab --help`).

Answer (score 1):

Can you kindly use this combination of keys:
   **Alt+PrintScreen+r+s+e+i+u+b.**

The **Alt+PrintScreen** should be depressed as you key in the other letters one at a time.

The combination send some low level commands independent of the system state and this is what each of them mean:

- r – takes the control of the keyboard back from X.
- s – writes the data from the disc cache to the hard disk.
- e – sends SIGTERM to all processes except init.
- i – sends SIGKILL to all processes except init
- u – remounts all the filesystems readonly (basically a measure to help you reboot safely)
- b – reboots the system

I am sure the syste will then respond after that.